# Good resource/book to learn about memory leaking in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm looking for a good resource/book to learn about memory leaking in C++.
I use Linux Ubuntu and QtCreator as a IDE ( is there a way to see them there ? ).

Comment: Presumably you want to learn about *preventing* memory leaks?

Comment: Is there enough information on this topic to warrant or fill a book?  Perhaps a chapter, but not an entire book.

Comment: After a good chapter i'm looking for. In Prata's C++ Primer is too little, and i refuse to read Thinking in C++ for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***What is a Memory Leak?***
A memory leak, occurs when a computer program consumes memory but is unable to release it back to the operating system. In C/C++ whenever a program allocates dynamic memory on the heap it should also release the same or it results in memory leak.

In C dynamic memory is allocated on Heap using the function `malloc`, the same memory is reclaimed by explicitly calling the function `free`.

In C++ dynamic memory is allocated on Heap using the operator `new` or `new[]`, the same is reclaimed through `delete` or `delete[]`.

***Resources to know more about memory Leaks?***
You can find many online tutorials and books to know more about the various common scenarios in which memory leaks are encountered.
[Here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++MemoryCorruptionAndMemoryLeaks.html) is one such valuable online tutorial.

***How can be memory leak detected?***
Various commercial and open source tools are available to detect memory leaks and memory corruptions for various platforms. Since you are specifically asking for Linux platform.
You can use `Valgrind` which is a very effective memory leak detection tool in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Use ANY good C++ book/resource.
Learn everything about dynamically allocated memory and the difference to auto variables.

You can avoid the most memory leaks by a good software design.

When you encounter memory leaks in your code you have to use your knowledge about them and a tool like **Valgrind** to detect and gather informations about them.

Comment: FYI, **Valgrind** is not available for all platforms, such as Windows.